# Serial version id mismatch issue between server and client class

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, serialversionuid

I am facing issues with serial version id mismatch.

My server is having code with serialVersionID=20150301L;
and myt client code is having diffrent so changed it manually but still facing the same issues.

Error:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.fedex.supplies.j2ee.common.client.reqresp.CustomerDataRequest; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 20150901L, local class serialVersionUID = -955959537118369236.
```

I tried option like implementing serilizable,manually defined serialVersionID same as server but getting the same error each time.

Comment: If you changed it manually, it wouldn't give the same error. The `local class serialVersionUID` is the number you specified. If it didn't change you didn't set it correctly and update your code.

Comment: Can you show us how you set the `serialVersionUID` in your code?

Comment: In other words you have to set it to what is in the stream, `20150901L`.

Comment: AND it has to be `private static final long`

Comment: Check your deployment strategy. Make sure you deploy the same package/classes which you use in your project. That means you should not set and compile serialVersionIDs on two different points, but only on one (and copy the compiled class e.g. in jar).

Comment: @AndreasL. I am using server Jar(in which serialVersionID is speciafiled) and client code is deployed in deffrent package...

Comment: Do you import the class from the server jar into your client code?

Comment: @TaufikPirjade You can't do that. The serialized class and the class present in deserialization have to agree in name, package, and `serialVersionUID`, *at least.* But if you had really used different packages you wouldn't have got this exception. Please clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 20150901L;
```

if you don't make it `private` and `static` and `final` it will be ignored.

Comment: According to the [Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100) it must also be `final`.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for the correction and the link. I have never tried to make it non-final. ;)

Comment: I think I've made it non-`private` a few times. The spec is pretty vague about it really.

Comment: @PeterLawrey not working for me showing same error... ;(

Comment: @TaufikPirjade That's not possible. You've changed the local classdesc. It can't be the same error as before, because the old error has the old local classdesc. Where would it get that from if you changed it? Are your sure you're running the new code?

Comment: According to both the spec mentioned in the first comment and java 8 doc for [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), it does not have to be private. It'll be nice, but not mandatory.